# How to keep the autolayout of xib then add this to a scrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, xib

I have an autolayout xib with constraints added in my application. 
Then I add my xib view to a scrollView lateral like a pageController.

But when I add this to the scrollView I get a lot of error with constraints and the outlets isn't showed properly. "[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints."

This is my xib class code:

```
@implementation InvitView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        nibname=@"Invit";

        [self addSubview:
         [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibname owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
            }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And I add my xib to the scrollView with this code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    float width = self.scroll.frame.size.width;
    float height = self.scroll.frame.size.height;

    int count = 0;

    InvitView *myView = [[InvitView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scroll.frame.origin.x, self.scroll.frame.origin.y, self.scroll.frame.size.width, self.scroll.frame.size.height)];

    [myView setFrame:CGRectMake(width*count++, 0, width, height)];
    [myView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    [self.scroll addSubview:myView];
}
```

I'm trying set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO; but with this code I lost all constraints, and I want keep this then add to the scrollView.

How can I keep my initial constraints in the xib?

**EDIT**

On the one hand, I have this constraints to my UIScrollView in my viewwController:

[image]

On the another hand I have this in my xib:

[image]

And the exactly log is:
[image]

Comment: "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints " is related to having wrong constraints set up! Could you please show what constraints you have added ?

Comment: I have added the info to my question. Hope be clear and get your help, thanks for your answer!

Comment: if you give height constraint to label, then you shold not give bottom constraint to the label.It is either (leading,trailing,top,height) or (leading,trailing,top,bottom)